# Using Symfony session's `migrate` method throws error on PHP 7.2

Tags: php, symfony, php-7.2

We are using a Guard authenticator on a Symfony app to authenticate via an external application. Within the `getCredentials` method of our `AbstractGuardAuthenticator` implementation, we use the `migrate` method on the Request's session to refresh the session.

```
/**
 * Called on every request and refreshes the user's session.
 * Attempts to get credentials (i.e. a token) from a request:
 *      If a token is present, attempts to log a user in.  Continues to the getUser method.
 *      If there is no token a user is logged in, the request continues.
 *      If there is no token and there is no logged in user, sends the User to authenticate.
 *
 * @param Request $request The current request
 * @return array|null If there is a token present, it is returned in an array; otherwise null is returned
 */
public function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    // Update the session lifetime
    // The migrate method regenerates the session to a new session id, but preserves
    // all attributes.  The first parameter is set to true so that the old session
    // is destroyed, and the second parameter resets the lifetime to 30 minutes.
    $request->getSession()->migrate(true, 30 * 60);

    // Check query params for token
    $token = $request->query->get('token');

    // When no token is provided:
    //  If user is logged in, skip authentication steps
    //  If no user is logged in, go to start method to authenticate
    if($token == null)
        return null;

    // Token provided, continue to getUser
    return ['token' => $token];
}
```

When running on PHP 7.1, this works fine. The `migrate` method returns true, which indicates a successful migration, [according to the docs](https://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.html#method_migrate). When running on PHP 7.2, I get this error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException:
Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time

at vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage.php:201
at Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->regenerate(true, 1800)
    (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session.php:185)
at Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session->migrate(true, 1800)
    (vendor\OrgOne\authentication-bundle\OrgOne\AuthenticationBundle\Security\TokenAuthenticator.php:55)
at OrgOne\AuthenticationBundle\Security\TokenAuthenticator->getCredentials(object(Request))
    (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Firewall\GuardAuthenticationListener.php:118)
```

How should we be using the `migrate` method or something similar in PHP 7.2?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this behavior with PHP 7.2.7 and symfony 4.2.

The `migrate` function will not generate the exception if called without parameters

`$request->getSession()->migrate()`

The lifetime specified in the `framework.yml` config will then be used. So you can set the cookie_lifetime with 1800 (= 30 * 60)

```
framework:
    ...
    session:
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
        cookie_lifetime: 1800
```